# Pandas/NumPy: concisely label first N values matching a mask

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a sorted Series like this:

```
[2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9]
```

I want to produce another Series or ndarray of the same length, where the first two odd numbers and the first two even numbers are labeled sequentially:

```
[0, 1, 2, _, _, 3]
```

The `_` values I don't really care about.  They can be zero.

Now I do it this way:

```
src = pd.Series([2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9])
odd = src % 2 != 0
where = np.hstack((np.where(odd)[0][:2], np.where(~odd)[0][:2]))
where.sort() # maintain ordering - thanks to @hpaulj
res = np.zeros(len(src), int)
res[where] = np.arange(len(where))
```

Can you do it more concisely?  The input will never be empty, but there might be no odds or no evens (in which case the result could have length 1, 2, or 3 instead of 4).

Comment: Does order matter?  In your example 2 evens occur before any odds,  But `[1,4,5,7,8,9]`  produces `[2, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0]`.  `res[np.sort(where)]=...` is an easy fix.  Or creating an intermediate boolean mask.

Comment: @hpaulj: Good question.  I do actually prefer it sorted.  I'll add `where.sort()` to my example solution (making it even less concise!).

Answer (score 1):

Great Problem!  I'm still exploring and learning.

I've basically stuck with what you've done so far with modest tweaks for efficiency.  I'll update if I think of anything else cool.

***conclusions***
So far, I've thrashed around alot and haven't improved much.

***my answer***
fast

```
odd = src.values % 2
even = 1 - odd
res = ((odd.cumsum() * odd) < 3) * ((even.cumsum() * even) < 3)
(res.cumsum() - 1) * res
```

***alternative 1***
pretty fast

```
a = src.values
odd = (a % 2).astype(bool)
rng = np.arange(len(a))

# same reason these are 2, we have 4 below
where = np.append(rng[~odd][:2], rng[odd][:2])
res = np.zeros(len(a), int)

# nature of the problem necessitates that this is 4
res[where] = np.arange(4)
```

---

***alternative 2***
not as quick, but creative

```
a = src.values
odd = a % 2
res = np.zeros(len(src), int)
b = np.arange(2)
c = b[:, None] == odd
res[(c.cumsum(1) * c <= 2).all(0)] = np.arange(4)
```

***alternative 3***
still slow

```
odd = src.values % 2
a = (odd[:, None] == [0, 1])
b = ((a.cumsum(0) * a) <= 2).all(1)
(b.cumsum() - 1) * b
```

---

***timing***
*code*

```
def pir3(src):
    odd = src.values % 2
    a = (odd[:, None] == [0, 1])
    b = ((a.cumsum(0) * a) <= 2).all(1)
    return (b.cumsum() - 1) * b

def pir0(src):
    odd = src.values % 2
    even = 1 - odd
    res = ((odd.cumsum() * odd) < 3) * ((even.cumsum() * even) < 3)
    return (res.cumsum() - 1) * res

def pir2(src):
    a = src.values
    odd = a % 2
    res = np.zeros(len(src), int)
    c = b[:, None] == odd
    res[(c.cumsum(1) * c <= 2).all(0)] = np.arange(4)
    return res

def pir1(src):
    a = src.values
    odd = (a % 2).astype(bool)
    rng = np.arange(len(a))
    where = np.append(rng[~odd][:2], rng[odd][:2])
    res = np.zeros(len(a), int)
    res[where] = np.arange(4)
    return res

def john0(src):
    odd = src % 2 == 0
    where = np.hstack((np.where(odd)[0][:2], np.where(~odd)[0][:2]))
    res = np.zeros(len(src), int)
    res[where] = np.arange(len(where))
    return res

def john1(src):
    odd = src.values % 2 == 0
    where = np.hstack((np.where(odd)[0][:2], np.where(~odd)[0][:2]))
    res = np.zeros(len(src), int)
    res[where] = np.arange(len(where))
    return res
```

`src = pd.Series([2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9])`
[image]

`src = pd.Series([2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9] * 10000)`
[image]